# find duplicates replace with suffix of column names pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a pandas df something like this

```
       ABC           DEF            item            color          char
   0   plt           yes            RoSe            Rose          Fragrant
   1   plt1          no            Violet          VIOLET           NA
   2   plt2          yes            Lily            White         Fragrant
   3   plt4          yes            ROSE            na            Fragrant
```

I want to now check in a list of columns and any value that is appearing in more than once anywhere, to be replaced with the value with suffix of column name. The search should be case-insensitive, but the replacement need not be. So my list of columns is

```
   my_list = ['item', 'color', 'char']
```

Expected output:

```
       ABC           DEF            item            color          char
   0   plt           yes          Rose_item        Rose_color     Fragrant
   1   plt1          no           Violet_item      Violet_color    Na_char
   2   plt2          yes            Lily           White          Fragrant
   3   plt4          yes          Rose_item        Na_color       Fragrant
```

Can someone please help me with this? Also, is there anyway we can exclude a word from the search? For example, I dont want the value of NA to be replaced. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the stacked columns as intermediate:

```
# stack and capitalize
s = df[my_list].fillna('Na').stack().str.capitalize()
# identify duplicates
m = s.duplicated(keep=False)
# modify duplicates
s[m] += '_'+s.index.get_level_values(1)[m]
# unstack and replace original
df[my_list] = s.unstack()
```

Output:

```
    ABC  DEF         item         color           char
0   plt  yes    Rose_item    Rose_color  Fragrant_char
1  plt1   no  Violet_item  Violet_color        Na_char
2  plt2  yes         Lily         White  Fragrant_char
3  plt4  yes    Rose_item      Na_color  Fragrant_char
```

Comment: thanks, but this is resulting in every value in selected columns to be given the column suffix. But I only want column suffix added to values that are duplicated across columns. If a value is repeating in only one column, I dont want it replaced. Only when this value is being repeated in different columns please

Comment: This is not what your expected output showed... Can you update it?